# mediator design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, class-diagram

In my system, I have 2 classes: User and LoginUser class. LoginUser is child of User. There may various communications (Friends request, photo requesr, Friends request accept etc) possible between 2 objects - User and LoginUser. On the basis of LoginUser's membership, there are various security privileges and on the basis of those privileges, different-different messages will be there.

Which design pattern I should use for the given scenario? I was thinking of using Mediator design pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by child?  LoginUser is a subclass of User or User has a LoginUser? You may want to describe what's contained in LoginUser and User a little more.

Comment: LoginUser is subclass of User. User contains attributes like name, email, membership etc. LoginUser contains some previleges for performing actions like editing, login etc.

Comment: Ok last question and I'll try to post up an answer - are all users LoginUser's?  If not, what's an example of a user who isn't

Comment: Yes. The communications have to be happened with LoginUser only. The classes are separated on the basis of behavior. Suppose I am logged in my system then I am the object of LoginUser and other users are objects of User class. The communications have to be happened between LoginUser and User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a design pattern, but I would split these two concepts: Privileges and User info.

From a readability stand-point, when I see a subclass, I usually assume there is some other mutually-exclusive subclass.  For example, if I see an Animal interface and a MeatEater subclass, I would assume that there is a VeggieEater subclass somewhere else.  The fact that LoginUser is a subclass and all Users are LoginUsers feels unnatural to me.

From a design point of view, you're LoginUser has 2 distinct responsibilties:
1) House user level information such as username, email, friends, etc
2) Determine privileges

I would try to break this up.  Such as

```
public class User { 
  // keep info in here 
  private String username;
  private String email;
}


public class Authorization {
   // this will determine access
   public Authorization(User user) { this.user = user; }

   public boolean isAccessAllowed(String someAction) { // ... }
}
```

Something like this would break up the distinct responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for the solution. Now I am able to distinct responsibilities. but I have to incorporate my messaging system also in place. I have thought of a Communicator class which communicates between LoginUser and User. all the methods like Request friends, request photo, accept friends request are part of my Communicator class. With the help of Authorization class, I can get the LoginUser privileges and use the same in my corresponding methods. now how can I incorporate my messaging system? On the basis of authorization/ methods I have different messages.

Comment: I'm still not sure I totally understand the Communicator's role.  Maybe you can edit your question and include some example code from each of these classes to give a better idea.